# Salesforce SOAP Service Login() only returns null values in visual studio service reference

Tags: c#, .net, soap, salesforce, soap-client

I am attempting to login to Salesforce from C#. I created a service reference for the partner WSDL and used the below snippet to try to login but the loginResult is always null.

```
var soapClient = new SoapClient("Soap", endpointUrl);
var loginResult = soapClient.Service.login(new loginRequest()
{
   username = userName,
   password = password
}).result;
```

This is what was generated in my config file after adding the service reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/27.0"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding"
                contract="Salesforce.Soap" name="Soap" />
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SoapBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Anyone have an idea as to why the login() method returns nothing?

Comment: I also saw this SO question but I don't want to use the Web Service Reference. Besides it didn't work either as it was the first one I tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841127/visual-studio-2010-soap-service-reference-returns-only-null-values

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you investigate and understand what is going on below the service before you use the magic of WFC and config files. It has been my experience that many times you can get the low level working to illuminate what the high level classes are doing on your behalf with generics.

A simple HTTP post via Google Chrome Postman will give you then needed working experience to know when the dreaded null login result is your code or bad login information :-)

**HTTP VERB:** POST

**URL:** https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0

**HEADERS:**

Content-Type:text/xml

SOAPAction: "login"

**BODY:**

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:login>
             <urn:username>[replace with your salesforce login id (email)]</urn:username>
             <urn:password>[replace with your salesforce password][replace with your salesforce security token]</urn:password>
          </urn:login>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you want a short 10 minute prescriptive developer lab on Kindle, take a look at [http://www.amazon.com/How-login-SalesforceTM-SOAP-minutes-ebook/dp/B00IHOOKMU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IHOOKMU)